# How can I call a function automatically whenever an endpoint is hit?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I currently have a function that we need to call in every endpoint. I was wondering if there is a good way to make it so I can just have the function get called automatically when any/certain endpoints are hit.

For instance, lets say I have a function in a controller class that returns values here.

```
      @GetMapping("/data")
  public Set<Mission> getdata() {
    return dataService.getData();
  }
```

Now in the class DataService, I have to manually call a function at the start to set up.

```
  public Set<Data> getData() {
    **functionIHaveToCall.setData();**
    ....
    return data;
  }
```

I have to do that for every end point right now because that function has to execute for a lot of them. Is there a way I can allow a piece of code to just run any time an endpoint is hit? I tried looking into @ModelAttribute and HandlerInterceptor but they don't seem to be quite what I am looking for. Unless I am misunderstanding something. What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Sure you can use AOP: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop

Comment: I would recommend using a Filter for this type of work.